# Adding a query string to a random URL

Tags: php, query-string

I want to add a query string to a URL, however, the URL format is unpredictable. The URL can be

- `http://example.com/page/` -> `http://example.com/page/?myquery=string`
- `http://example.com/page` -> `http://example.com/page?myquery=string`
- `http://example.com?p=page` -> `http://example.com?p=page&myquery=string`

These are the URLs I'm thinking of, but it's possible that there are other formats that I'm not aware of.

I'm wondering if there is a standard, library or a common way to do this. I'm using PHP.

Edit: I'm using [Cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16013948/12637) explanation and [Passerby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014036/12637) code. There is another [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014276/12637) by Hamza but I guess it'd be better to use PHP functions and also have cleaner/shorter code.

Comment: Maybe you should use mod rewrite with .htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function addQuery($url,array $query)
{
    $cache=parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY);
    if(empty($cache)) return $url."?".http_build_query($query);
    else return $url."&".http_build_query($query);
}

// test
$test=array("http://example.com/page/","http://example.com/page","http://example.com/?p=page");
print_r(array_map(function($v){
    return addQuery($v,array("myquery"=>"string"));
},$test));
```

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/bGdXJ#v530)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there is a standard, library or a common way to do this. I'm using PHP.

Depends on how failsafe – and thereby more complex – you want it to be.

The simplest way would be to look for whether there’s a `?` in the URL – if so, append `&myquery=string`, else append `?myquery=string`. This should cover most cases of standards-compliant URLs just fine.

If you want it more complex, you could take the URL apart using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and then [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), then add the key `myquery` with value `string` to the array the second function returns – and then put it all back together again, using [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for the new query string part.

Answer (score 1):

Some spaghetti Code:

```
echo addToUrl('http://example.com/page/','myquery', 'string').'<br>';
echo addToUrl('http://example.com/page','myquery', 'string').'<br>';
echo addToUrl('http://example.com/page/wut/?aaa=2','myquery', 'string').'<br>';
echo addToUrl('http://example.com?p=page','myquery', 'string');

function addToUrl($url, $var, $val){
    $array = parse_url($url);
    if(isset($array['query'])){
        parse_str($array['query'], $values);
    }
    $values[$var] = $val;
    unset($array['query']);

    $options = '';$c = count($values) - 1;
    $i=0;
    foreach($values as $k => $v){
        if($i == $c){
            $options .= $k.'='.$v;
        }else{
            $options .= $k.'='.$v.'&';
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $return = $array['scheme'].'://'.$array['host'].(isset($array['path']) ? $array['path']: '') . '?' . $options;
    return $return;
}
```

Results:

```
http://example.com/page/?myquery=string
http://example.com/page?myquery=string
http://example.com/page/wut/?aaa=2&myquery=string
http://example.com?p=page&myquery=string
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function, I think that's what you're looking for, and maybe a bit of `parse_str()`, too.