# Magic trick to get the correct url?

Tags: php

I am about to make a system that automaticly puts `&pni=something` behind an URL. It would be easy if the url just was *http://t.co/something.php* with "?pni=...." but users can also have *http://t.co/something.php?myown=paramater* and then the system should add `&` instead of `?`

How can I put the `pni` parameter behind the URL and to be valid every time? I've tried this without luck.

```
<?php
function nice($in){
  $out = parse_url($in);
  return $out['scheme'] . "://" . $out['host'] . $out['path'] . "?" . $out['query'];
}

$urls = array(
  "http://t.co/something.php?w=23&",
  "http://t.co/something.php?w=23&dfdf=",
  "http://t.co/something.php?",
  "http://t.co/something.php",
  "http://t.co/something",
  "http://t.co/something.php?w=23&dfdf=34&hvem",
);

foreach ( $urls as $url):
  echo print_r(nice($url)) . "<br/>";
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Does [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) not do what you want?

Comment: This has already been [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16013703).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function nice($in) {
    $out = parse_url($in);
    if ($out['query'] != "") {
        $out['query'] = "pni=something&".$out['query'];
    }
    else { 
      $out['query'] = "pni=something";
    }

    return $out['scheme'] . "://" . $out['host'] . $out['path'] . "?" . $out['query'];
}
```

Comment: well it outputs http://t.co/something.php?w=23&&pni=something1
http://t.co/something.php?w=23&dfdf=&pni=something1
http://t.co/something.php?pni=something1
http://t.co/something.php?pni=something1
http://t.co/something?pni=something1
http://t.co/something.php?w=23&dfdf=34&hvem&pni=something1 "hvem" should be hvem=& and not hvem& and same as "?w=23&&pni=something1" should be "?w=23&pni=something1"

Answer (score 0):

You can access the query string specifically using

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

If it is empty you can use

```
$url .= '?arg=val';
```

If query string is ! empty

```
$url .= '&arg=val';
```

Comment: I get exactly the same when I switch between PHP and perl

Answer (score 0):

check if there is any `"?"` in the url and concat the `pni=something` to it accordingly.

```
function nice($url){
    if(strpos($url,"?")!==false){
        return $url."&pni=something";
    }else{
        return $url."?pni=something";
    }
}
```